# passing js function a value when using Rails button_to_function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a table of what I call resources, want to show in a jquery dialog a particular record when user clicks button in a row.

in the table I'm doing:

```
<td><%=button_to_function 'Show','showresource1()',:class =>"ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all", :id => resource.id %></td>
```

then in javascript I want to pass jQuery dialog the resource.id and open the dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function showresource1()
  {
    jQuery("#resource_details").load( 'http://localhost:3000/resources/show/4').dialog('open');    
  }
</script>
```

I can open the dialog and load this static URL, but am stumped re passing resource.id from the button_to_function down to the js function.

is button_to_function the right way to go and if so, how do I get URL defined in js?

Answer (score 1):

It should be like code below

```
<% for res_id in ids %>
<%=button_to_function "Show", "show_resource('#{res_id}')" %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function show_resource(res_id)
  {
    jQuery("#resource_details").load( 'http://localhost:3000/resources/show/' + res_id).dialog('open');
  }
</script>
```